# Intent for over-temperature recovery on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, temperature

We have found that our Android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab Active2) kills all apps with a warning message when the battery temperature exceeds about 55 deg. C.  The device does not power-down however.

What we want to do is find a way to automatically restart our app when the temperature has come down to a safe level.  We are going to try using the alarm manager to schedule a periodic temperature check (assuming the alarms have not been cleared), but is there an specific intent related to the over-temperature condition?

Comment: For anyone interested, what we found after further testing was that the alarms registered with AlarmManager do not get cleared as a result of the over-temperature event.  Our broadcast receiver continues to receive intents from the Alarm Manager even while over-temperature.  If we try to restart our app while the temperature is still high, Android kills it immediately.  When the temperature has fallen to a safe level, the restart succeeds.